# Error: To use plugins requiring `addCSS` (e.g. keyframes, media queries), please wrap your application in the StyleRoot component

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React JS. While learning I got this issue. I don' know why it's giving this error even I have installed radium by command npm install --save radium
Please find my code below -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Radium, { StyleRoot } from 'radium';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const style = {
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        color: '#111',

        '@media (min-width: 500px)': {
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          color: 'red'
        }
    };

    return (
      <StyleRoot>
      <div className="App" style={style}>
        dsdsdsds
      </div>
      </StyleRoot>
    )
  }
}

export default Radium(App);
```

Comment: If you don't have to use Radium I suggesting looking into Emotion -> https://emotion.sh

Answer (score 1):

In Radium you can't use media queries, keyframes, etc directly under `<StyleRoot>`. You have to add one more component, which will be wrapped in `<StyleRoot>`:

```
class StyledDiv extends Component {
  render() {
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: "#ccc",
      color: "#111",

      "@media (min-width: 500px)": {
        backgroundColor: "yellow",
        color: "red"
      }
    };
    return <div style={style}>dsdsdsds</div>;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyleRoot>
        <StyledDiv />
      </StyleRoot>
    );
  }
}

export default Radium(App);
```